# Different indentation styles in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

My team prefers K&R indentation style and I am the only one who prefers Java style for indentation.

Is there any way in IntelliJ to format code to Java style indentation and convert it back to K&R indentation before committing the code?

Comment: Every time I've worked with a single person who was relying on blanket formatting everything before committing, every change of theirs was filled with tonnes of not just cosmetic changes, but cosmetic changes that made things objectively harder to read. Do you really want to *that guy* who is making things actively worse because he is too stubborn to adapt? I honestly believe the best advice is to just suck it up and follow the conventions established by your project.

Comment: What Michael said. Seriously. Don't. Be. That. Guy. You will waste a ton of your own time and earn your co-workers scorn. This is (usually) a purely a personal preference so you (likely) have no factual reason to push for one style over the other. Just go with the flow, there are bigger things to worry about. (although, I do agree with your preference...)

Comment: There should not be any changes if I just format the curly braces back to the original format. I understand you guys, but K&R style is a pain after years of coding in java style...